# Two-factor authentication only on a new device

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using two-factor authentication with IdentityServer4. Every time a user try sign-in need to pass through 2FA (two-factor authentication). Could someone point me in the good way to only have that 2FA one time if the device to which it is being used for sign-in is a new one? Where should I need to look for documentation about that?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can use cookie to decide whether to do 2FA or not for the user.

Comment: Use a long-lived cookie to indicate that 2fa has taken place on that device, or use device fingerprinting and store list of 'trusted' devices.